Why is it when making a lewis structure that it seems like one atom creates the electron bond instead of electrons from two atoms?
For example, when I am trying to make a Lewis structure for NO2, I always get tripped up because one of the bonds is single-bonded but the oxygen has 6 other electrons while Nitrogen just has one, so it seems like that single bond just came from the Nitrogen instead of the nitrogen and oxygen.

The compound $\ce{NO2}$ is a bit puzzling -- because it's a free radical. Look at it's structure in Wikipedia:

[T]he ground electronic state of nitrogen dioxide is a doublet
state, since nitrogen has one unpaired electron... The lone
electron... also means that this compound is a free radical
so the formula [may be written $\ce{*NO2}$.]

